# Currency exchange rates timeout error via Webservicex and Google Finance

Tags: php, magento, cron, currency

My exchange rates are not updating. Cron is set to run it daily. Initially received email error report with several lines relating to failed updates of currency pairs, e.g.

> Currency update warnings:
>   WARNING: Cannot retrieve rate from http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=NZD&ToCurrency=BAM

However other currency pairs not noted in the email were failing to update too. I used Magento Connect to install the Google Finance alternative, but still getting an error emailed after cron runs.

> Currency update warnings:
>   WARNING: Cannot retrieve rate from [Google finance URL]

Checked the Github repo and xml files do not differ from the Connect version.

When manually attempting to update via either service in admin System > Manage Currency > Rates

I receive a 500 error:

> Request Timeout
>
> This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it >should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to >increase 'Connection Timeout'.

php.ini in htdocs root had

```
max_execution_time = 260
```

which I changed to

```
max_execution_time = 18000
```

But no improvement. I've tried searching here and elsewhere, can't find reference to the same error. I'm using CE 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Seems webservicex is down at the moment. We have the same error since three days. Try to contact them cause the asp.net makes trouble. 
You will see it if you open [this link](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=EUR&ToCurrency=USD) in the browser

Maybe wait a little bit :)

Comment: I was aware webservicex is down - it has happened several times in the past and now I'd like to solve this issue of unreliability by using a different service. But I get the same two errors as described above after trying to switch to Google Finance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
It appeared to be a Google quota thing, once I reduced the number of currency pairs I was trying to fetch (now under 100, it was over 120 previously), the timeout error stopped and retrieval was possible.